# Netbeans: Auto Format - Prevent Netbean return multiline variable to 1 line

Tags: php, netbeans, formatting, autoformatting

i have problem about auto format in NetBean.

I want my code like these:

```
Class(
    var1, 
    var2, 
    var3, 
    var4
);
```

But after formating my code become:

```
 Class(
    var1, var2, var3, var4
);
```

Anyone tell me how to stop this in NetBeans.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think it will make any difference to your logic.

Comment: yes but i have a testing code program and it tell me "Either split this list into multiple lines, aligned at column ... or put all arguments on 1 line ...". But 1 line is more than 120 character so i want to use multiple line so that this program won't warning me anymore.

Comment: You couldn't control neatbeans formatting. The better solution is not format if you like all variables on separate line.

Comment: I think we can change format at Options>Editor>Formatting?  but maybe netbeans doesn't have a way to change this proplem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Formatting->...->Wrapping->Method Call Arguments->"Always" (or "If Long").

But this option is not perfect, unfortunately -- has some quite ugly side effects...